# How do I use $inject (or similar) in a angular factory method

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I gather that I cannot use $inject in a factory method. 
How do I inject without using a direct function in the factory definition.
Instead of     PopupService.$inject('$rootScope'); which is throwing an error, what is the equivalent to inject into a angular factory?

```
  angular
        .module('refdata.legalentity')
        .factory('PopupService', PopupService);

    PopupService.$inject('$rootScope');

    function PopupService($rootScope) {

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the $inject property to an array of the dependencies you'd like to inject.

```
PopupService.$inject = ['$rootScope'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like this without using `$inject`:

```
var app = angular.module('refdata.legalentity');

app.factory("PopupService", ["$rootScope", PopupService]);

function PopupService($rootScope) {
    var popupText = "something to popup";
    return {
        getPopupText: function(){
            return popupText;
        }
    }
}
```

Although I think @Anthony's answer is the one you're looking for.